# In ruby, how to find the index of first non-whitespace character of given string

Tags: ruby, regex

In ruby, how to find the index of first non-whitespace (non-tab, non-space, non-newline) character of given string.

For example, given string `"\t\nstring"`, the index of first non-tab, non-space, non-newline character will be 2 which is 's'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With this notation:

```
/\S/ =~ "\t\nstring"
# => 2
```

Comment: Your solution is the best for me :) Deleted mine

Comment: @Ursus: I'm not agree, your solution is interesting too.

Comment: @Ursus, your solution was nice too, please undelete.

Comment: Ok guys. But I think your is more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one. `s` is your string

```
s.index(s.lstrip[0])
```